# Need help on Pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need help on pivot.. My i/p and o/p as below(pls see the attached image)..Could u pls help me on the query...
[image]

Comment: Do not post links to images. Describe the problem as clear as possible. Provide DDL and DML(sample of data) so we could reproduce your situation as fast as possible, and desired result.

Comment: @Anjan Das i had given solution for query go through it,it will helps you

Answer (score 1):

Here created sample data for getting result

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp
;WIth cte(EmployeeID, Activity_Date,Activity_Type)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'6/20/2016' ,'Mail_send'       UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'6/22/2011' ,'Mail_Received'   UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'10/11/2016','Mail_Replied'    UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'10/31/2016','Mail_deleted'    UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2/11/2016' ,'Mail_Forwared'
)

SELECT * INTO  #Temp FROM cte
```

We can get the result by using dynamic Sql with Pivot

```
DECLARE @dynamicCol nvarchar(max),
        @Sql nvarchar(max)


SELECT @dynamicCol=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' +QUOTENAME(Activity_Type)  FROM  #Temp
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SET @Sql='
            SELECT  [EmployeeID] , '+ @dynamicCol +' From
            (
            SELECT * From
            #temp
            )AS Src
            PIVOT 
            (
            MAX([Activity_Date]) For [Activity_Type] IN ('+@dynamicCol+')
            )
            AS Pvt
            '

PRINT @Sql

EXEC(@Sql)
```

Result

```
EmployeeID  Mail_deleted    Mail_Forwared   Mail_Received   Mail_Replied    Mail_send
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           NULL            NULL            NULL            10/11/2016      6/20/2016
2           NULL            2/11/2016       6/22/2011       NULL            NULL
3           10/31/2016      NULL            NULL            NULL            NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Query, this should serve your purpose:

```
select * from
(select [Employee Id],Activity_Date,Activity_Type from Employee_Activity) tbl
pivot
(
max(Activity_Date) for Activity_Type in (Mail_Send,Mail_Received,Mail_Replied,Mail_deleted,Mail_Forwarded)
)as pvt
```